# How to write data to the next sheet while generating CSV?

Tags: java, csv

How to write data to the next sheet while generating CSV in Java?

```
                    response.setContentType("text/csv");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition",
                "inline; filename=\"mGovData.csv\"");


        OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

        byte[] bom = new byte[] { (byte) 0xEF, (byte) 0xBB, (byte) 0xBF };
        outputStream.write(bom); // adds BOM

        Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                outputStream, "UTF-8"));

        if (otmstatus != null
                || (StringUtils.isNotBlank(otmfrmDate) && StringUtils
                        .isNotBlank(otmtoDate))
                || (otmdaystate != null && from != null && to != null)) {

            // Write the content
            if (otmfrmDate != null && otmtoDate != null) {
                from = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(otmfrmDate);
                // to = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(otmtoDate);
                DateFormat d = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                to = d.parse(otmtoDate);
                to.setHours(23);
                to.setMinutes(59);
                to.setSeconds(59);
            }

            otmConfigDtos = otmManager.getOtmDetailsForReport(otmstatus,
                    from, to, sp_Id, otmdaystate, otmphoneNo, msgText);

            String csvTitles = getText("lbl.report.generate.pdf.text.otm")
                    + "," + "\n"
                    + getText("lbl.report.generate.pdf.text.documentdate")
                    + new Date().toString() + "," + "\n"
                    + getText("lbl.report.generate.pdf.text.reportdate")
                    + " "
                    + getText("lbl.report.generate.pdf.text.dateform")
                    + " " + DateFormatUtils.format(from, "dd/MM/yyyy")
                    + " " + getText("lbl.report.generate.pdf.text.dateto")
                    + " " + DateFormatUtils.format(to, "dd/MM/yyyy") + "\n";

            out.write(csvTitles);

out.flush();
        out.close();
        outputStream.close();
}
```

I want to know if the data written on the CSV is too bulky. Then how can we move it to the next sheet?

Comment: csv does not have a notion of 'sheets'.  Spreads sheets do.

Comment: Thank you jayan.. But it downloaded in excel format only in webpage .. Excel has limit of arround 10 lakhs rows only right?

Comment: Sure, Excel can load CSV data, and Excel does have the concept of 'sheets', but CSV does not.  It is a much simpler format than Excel uses.

Comment: @ Vicky -  Creating a spreadsheet is pretty easy, your customer may like it.  Try apache-poi.

Answer (score 0):

You can create next csv file if in firstone certain number of rows completed. And in second csv if certain rows completed, then you can write next csv file.

But in my suggestion is , write that data to a database, then everything will be very simple.  Data insert, retrieval, edit etc etc will be very simple

Comment: But i generate csv from dynamicaly retrieved DB records only. So i dont know how many records dynamically fetched out from DB.. If it exceeds maximum then how can i create next csv as you said?

Comment: @Vicky - please tell me what is your use with this generated csv?

Comment: REPORT ANALYSIS FOR GOVERNMENT